# how to query results based on data in a db row

Tags: php, mysqli

All right. I asked a question looking for suggestions on here once, and I was told that wasn't allowed. I was told to state a specific problem, and ask for a specific answer. So as per moderator  instruction here I go.

I have two tables in my db. One table is nothing but several rows filled with different category options. Then on my other table there is a row called *cat* where one of the category terms found in the first row is stored.

I want to query out all of my category options from th table of nothing but categories as hyperlinks. Then based on the link chose run a query that looks something like this

```
SELECT cat FROM categories WHERE categiories=chosen cat term
```

I have general knowledge in php so I could figure out how to do what I want with a point in the right direction. My specific problem is that I do not know what to look for. Can someone please tell me what to look for? I have no problem with the query. My main problem is where would I point the hyperlink so it generates the page with the select statement upon request. What can I look for that will help me figure out how to do this? i am very good at dissecting and figuring things out.

Comment: Point it to another PHP file.

Comment: Well, yeah, but what goes in said other php file..  Ya know?

Answer (score 0):

Point it to another PHP file via hyperlink like this

```
another.php?term=foo
```

on the another page [connect to PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info) and have a code like this

```
$stm = $pdo->prepare("SELECT cat FROM categories WHERE categiories = ?");
$stm->execute(array($_GET['term']));
$cats = $stm->fetchAll();
```

now you can iterate over `$cats` array

Comment: How do I get the term from clicking the hyper link though?

Comment: Note `$_GET['term']` thing - it is the one.

Comment: Well yes $GET gets the term but how does the html send it without a form..? Wouldnt i need an input named term?

Comment: What I mean is that what do I put in my hyperlink to make each link unique and then how do i get that uniqe piece of information in the php using the GET

Comment: If you have no idea on basic HTML, you have to ask another question, titled "How do hyperlinks in HTML look like".

Comment: WTF are you talking about? I know how a hyperlink works. I cant simply put <a href="shit.php">shit</a> and expect it to work.. What I was clearly asking was how to make it look so it work in conjunction with the php script.. Woul I use %S?

Comment: You asked *clealy*? Please give a little peak more information what you have already done and what you want to do.

Comment: All right. Let me simplify it. How can I run an if else statement on a php page based on which hyperlink is clicked that links to the php page?

Comment: could I do my link like `<a href="cat.php?cat=%s">' . $row["cat"] . '</a>` and then something like `$sort = $_REQUEST['cat'];` in my cat.php

Answer (score 0):

Put somewhere in your HTML the link like this.

```
<a href="phpFileToHandleRequest.php?term=yourTerm">Link</a>
```

You can think of the PHP-file getting a param like that. Just read the param that way:

```
$term = $_GET["term"];
```

Comment: But then i'd need and input wouldnt I?

Comment: Do you want to get the term from an input field?